# I am trying to run a code to tell me True/False based on info in a dataframe, but it always responds False

Tags: python, dataframe, loops

I am trying to iterate through the rows of the DataFrame and update the values from False to True for each of the appropriate genre columns if that genre appears in the original Genre column.

```
genre_list = ['Action', 'Adventure', 'Sci-Fi','Mystery','Horror','Thriller','Animation','Comedy','Family','Fantasy', 'Drama','Music','Biography','Romance','History','Crime','Western','War','Musical','Sport']

for genres in df.Genre:
  df[genres] = False
for index, row in df.iterrows():
  Genre = str(row['Genre']).split(', ')
for genres in Genre:
  if genre in genres:
    df.at[index, genre] = True
```

However, when I run the code, the results give me false every time. I have tried adjusting the loops and taking it out of a loop completely but it continues to give me false.

```
    Rank                   Title                  Genre  \
995   996    Secret in Their Eyes    Crime,Drama,Mystery   
996   997         Hostel: Part II                 Horror   
997   998  Step Up 2: The Streets    Drama,Music,Romance   
998   999            Search Party       Adventure,Comedy   
999  1000              Nine Lives  Comedy,Family,Fantasy 

     Runtime (Minutes)  Rating  Votes  ...  Adventure,Biography  \
995                111     6.2  27585  ...                False   
996                 94     5.5  73152  ...                False   
997                 98     6.2  70699  ...                False   
998                 93     5.6   4881  ...                False   
999                 87     5.3  12435  ...                False   

     Adventure,Biography,Crime  Comedy,Drama,Musical  Comedy,Family,Romance  \
995                      False                 False                  False   
996                      False                 False                  False   
997                      False                 False                  False   
998                      False                 False                  False   
999                      False                 False                  False   

     Biography,Drama,Family  Drama,Fantasy,Musical  Adventure,Family  \
995                   False                  False             False   
996                   False                  False             False   
997                   False                  False             False   
998                   False                  False             False   
999                   False                  False             False   

     Adventure,Comedy,Fantasy  Drama,Family,Music  Comedy,Family,Fantasy  
995                     False               False                  False  
996                     False               False                  False  
997                     False               False                  False  
998                     False               False                  False  
999                     False               False                  False  

[5 rows x 232 columns]
```

I am new to Python so I don't really know much about how the loops work but I can't see anything wrong with this loop.

I've tried going through each line and re-writing the codes but it's always false.

Comment: What is the value of `genre`? I see  no assignment  to  it.

Comment: `if genre in genres:` Yes, where is the `genre` variable assigned?

Comment: I see! I just changed it from 'genre' to 'genres' as I had previously written at the beginning. I am still getting false for all of my results though.

Comment: Use a debugger or simply `print` your variables during / after the loops and see what they actually are - not what you think.

Comment: That didn't help me fix it :( ! All of he variables were what they were expected to be.

Comment: The second for loop keeps recreating a new variable called `Genre`, which overwrites the `Genre` variable from the previous loop iteration.  So at the end of the loop, `Genre` will only have the **last** row of the dataframe.  It feels like you intended to accumulate **all** of the genres in a list or something like that, but that's not what the loop is actually doing...